# Overlapping times

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, overlap

I have a table like this:

```
Id, TimeStart, TimeFinished
```

I need to find any `TimeStart` that begins prior to `TimeFinished`, but has a higher `Id`, that means an overlapping time.

```
Id  TimeStart   TimeFinished
1   2014-01-01  2014-01-02
2   2014-01-02  2014-01-03
3   2014-01-02  2014-01-04
```

This is found in row 3. Here `TimeStart < TimeFinished` in row 2.
(Or find row 2 where `TimeFinished > TimeStart` in row 3)

Comment: What did you try so far? What is the **specific** problem with the query you tried? Please read [ask] and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in [help]

Comment: Pred's right, you'll find your stay at StackOverflow much more agreeable if you can try fixing things yourself first, then come to us when that fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try left outer join :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   table t1
       LEFT JOIN table t2
              ON t1.Id > t2.Id
                 AND t1.TimeStart < t2.TimeFinished
WHERE  t2.Id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the information from the first record, you an use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t.id > t2.id and t.TimeStart > t2.TimeFinish
             );
```